# Column "dbo" is not allowed in this context, and the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.getListOfConference" could not be found

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, custom-function

I've got problem with my custom function. I want it to get back table of names of my conference users. Here is the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getListOfConference(@idConference int)
RETURNS Table
AS
RETURN
SELECT Employee_name FROM dbo.Employee WHERE ID_Employee 
    IN (SELECT ID_Employee FROM dbo.Conference WHERE ID_Conference LIKE @idConference);
```

And the message:

> Column "dbo" is not allowed in this context, and the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.getListOfConference" could not be found.

This message showed when I want to check this function like that:

```
PRINT dbo.getListOfConference(254712);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a table valued function, but you are want to use it as a scalar function.  No-can-do.

You can select from it:

```
select *
from dbo.getListOfConference(254712);
```